# Angular reactive from. FormArray. Cannot find control with path

Tags: angular, forms, angular-reactive-forms

I want to output a form in which one field is an array, and for each element of the array I need to output my inputs.

Component:

```
userData.contacts = [
{contact_type: "phone", value: "380666666666"},
{contact_type: "email", value: "ggg@gg.gg"},
{contact_type: "website", value: "www.good.co"}
];

this.contactInfoForm = new FormGroup ({
          contacts: this.fb.array (userData.contacts)
        });
```

HTML:

```
<form [formGroup] = "contactInfoForm" novalidate (ngSubmit) = "submit ('contactInfoForm')">
<div formArrayName = "contacts" * ngFor = "let contact of contactInfoForm.get ('contacts'). controls; let i = index;">
              <div formGroupName = "i">
                <label> {{contact.value.contact_type}} </ label>
                <input formControlName = "value">
              </ div>
            </ div>
</ form>
```

If to deduce in the console the form that there an object with a heap of the data.

```
  asyncValidator: null
controls:
contacts: FormArray
asyncValidator: null
controls: Array (3)
0: FormControl {validator: null, asyncValidator: null, _onCollectionChange: ƒ, pristine: true, touched: false, ...}
1: FormControl {validator: null, asyncValidator: null, _onCollectionChange: ƒ, pristine: true, touched: false, ...}
2: FormControl {validator: null, asyncValidator: null, _onCollectionChange: ƒ, pristine: true, touched: false, ...}
length: 3
__proto__: Array (0)
dirty: (...)
disabled: (...)
enabled: (...)
errors: null
invalid: (...)
length: (...)
parent: (...)
pending: (...)
pristine: true
root: (...)
status: DISABLED
statusChanges: EventEmitter {_isScalar: false, observers: Array (0), closed: false, isStopped: false, hasError: false, ...}
touched: false
untouched: (...)
updateOn: (...)
valid: (...)
validator: null
value: (3) [{...}, {...}, {...}]
valueChanges: EventEmitter {_isScalar: false, observers: Array (0), closed: false, isStopped: false, hasError: false, ...}
_onCollectionChange: ƒ ()
_onDisabledChange: []
_parent: FormGroup {validator: null, asyncValidator: null, _onCollectionChange: ƒ, pristine: true, touched: false, ...}
__proto__: AbstractControl
__proto__: Object
dirty: (...)
disabled: (...)
enabled: (...)
errors: null
invalid: (...)
parent: (...)
pending: (...)
pristine: true
root: (...)
status: DISABLED
statusChanges: EventEmitter {_isScalar: false, observers: Array (0), closed: false, isStopped: false, hasError: false, ...}
touched: false
untouched: (...)
updateOn: (...)
valid: (...)
validator: null
value: {contacts: Array (3)}
valueChanges: EventEmitter {_isScalar: false, observers: Array (0), closed: false, isStopped: false, hasError: false, ...}
_onCollectionChange: ƒ ()
_onDisabledChange: []
__proto__: AbstractControl
```

I have tried to derive the information in different ways. It does not work. Even if stupidly copy-paste pieces from examples in the Internet. The same problems. The same mistakes.

Error:

```
 Cannot find control with path: 'contacts -> 0 -> value'
```

Also tried:

```
<input [formControlName]="contact.value.value">
```

Got error:

> contacts -> 0 -> 380666666666

Comment: your `*ngFor` should not be within your `formArrayName=...` element but one child below. You should `ngFor` children of `formArray`.

Comment: i have tried before. also did not work. but i will try now again

Comment: not helped. nothing changed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide array of `FormControl` elements for your contacts, instead of plain array.

```
const formControlArray = [];
userData.contacts.forEach(contact => {
  formControlArray.push(new FormControl(contact.value));
})

this.contactInfoForm = new FormGroup ({
  contacts: this.fb.array(formControlArray)
});
```

But, I am not sure the FormArray is the best choice for your use case, since elements must have different names. 
You can just dynamically add controls this way too:

```
this.contactInfoForm = new FormGroup({});

userData.contacts.forEach(contact => {
  contactInfoForm.addControl(contact.contact_type, new FormControl(contact.value));
})
```

Comment: i dont wanna use map or foreach. FormBuilder.array() is standard feature. i wanna use it) but thx.

Comment: But you still would would need to wrap your contact data in FormControl. FormArray constructor doesn't support just plain objects.

Answer (score 0):

Component:

```
 userData.contacts = [{
        contact_type: "phone",
        value: "380666666666"
    }, {
        contact_type: "email",
        value: "ggg@gg.gg"
    }, {
        contact_type: "website",
        value: "www.good.co"
    }];

    this.contactInfoForm = new FormGroup({
        contacts: this.fb.array([
            ...this.userData.contacts.map(({ contact_type, value }) => {
                return this.fb.group({
                    contact_type,
                    value
                });
            })
        ])
    });
```

HTML:

```
 <form [formGroup]="contactInfoForm" novalidate (submit)="submit('contactInfoForm')">
        <div formArrayName="contacts" *ngFor="let contact of contactInfoForm.get('contacts').controls; let i = index;">
            <div [formGroupName]="i" >
                <label>{{ contact.value.contact_type }}</label>
                <input formControlName="value">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Works fine. but i still doesn't like to use map method.

Comment: great. I am not sure you can avoid using `map` or `forEach`. You need anyway to iterate over your contacts and create multiple FormGroup elements.